# Powershell: How can I use an array or hashtable as an inline lookup

Tags: arrays, powershell, hashtable

Using Powershell I am calling `win32_computersystem`. I want to list data about the machine including `$_thermalstate` - Here is my code

The code looks as though it should work but returns a empty value. I want to create an inline array or hash table that the value `$_.thermalstate` references.

```
Get-WmiObject win32_computersystem | select Name, Model, Caption, @{n="Timezone"; e={$_.currenttimezone}}, Description, DNShostname,Domain,@{n='Domain Role'; E={$_.domainrole}},Roles,Status,@{n='System Type'; e={$_.systemtype}},@{n='Thermal State'; e={$_.thermalstate[@{'3'='safe'}]}}
```

Output

```
Name          : MYPC
Model         : Latitude E5470
Caption       : MYPC
Timezone      : 600
Description   : AT/AT COMPATIBLE
DNShostname   : MYPC
Domain        : work.biz
Domain Role   : 1
Roles         : {LM_Workstation, LM_Server, NT}
Status        : OK
System Type   : x64-based PC
Thermal State : Safe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks like you are trying to declare/initialize a hash table while also trying to use thermalstate as a hash array.
If you initialize the hash array first, the code looks like this:

```
$h = @{'3'='safe'}; Get-WmiObject win32_computersystem | select Name, Model, Caption, @{n="Timezone"; e={$_.currenttimezone}}, Description, DNShostname,Domain,@{n='Domain Role';E={$_.domainrole}},Roles,Status,@{n='System Type'; e={$_.systemtype}},@{n='Thermal State'; e={$h[$_.thermalstate.toString()]}}
```

Answer (score 3):

your lookup structure was ... wrong. [*grin*]

replace the last line of this reformatted version of your code ...

```
Get-WmiObject win32_computersystem |
    Select-Object Name, Model, Caption,
        @{n="Timezone"; e={$_.currenttimezone}},
        Description, DNShostname,Domain,
        @{n='Domain Role'; E={$_.domainrole}},
        Roles,Status,
        @{n='System Type'; e={$_.systemtype}},
        @{n='Thermal State'; e={$_.thermalstate[@{'3'='safe'}]}}
```

... with this line ...

```
@{n='Thermal State'; e={@{'3'='Safe'}["$($_.ThermalState)"]}}
```

note that the lookup table is on the OUTSIDE of the `[]` and that the value is forced to a string.

---

however, i would NOT do it this way. it's too finicky. create the lookup table BEFORE your call and use that to perform the lookup.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://wutils.com/wmi/root/cimv2/win32_computersystem/

```
ThermalState property
CIMTYPE         'uint16'
Description     'The ThermalState property identifies the enclosure's thermal state when last booted.'
MappingStrings  ['SMBIOS|Type 3|System Enclosure or Chassis|Thermal State']
read            True
ValueMap        ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
Values          ['Other', 'Unknown', 'Safe', 'Warning', 'Critical', 'Non-recoverable']
ThermalState property is in 1 class (Win32_ComputerSystem) of ROOT\cimv2 and in 2 namespaces
```

You could create an enum

```
enum ThermalState {
Other          = 1
Unknown        = 2
Safe           = 3
Warning        = 4
Critical       = 5
NonRecoverable = 6
}
```

And use that to get a verbose response from the property

```
Get-WmiObject win32_computersystem | Select-Object Name, Model, Caption, 
    @{n="Timezone"; e={$_.currenttimezone}}, Description, DNShostname,Domain,
    @{n='Domain Role';E={$_.domainrole}},Roles,Status,
    @{n='System Type'; e={$_.systemtype}},
    @{n='Thermal State'; e={[ThermalState]$_.thermalstate}}
```

Sample output

```
Name          : HP-G1610
Model         : ProLiant MicroServer Gen8
Caption       : HP-G1610
Timezone      : 120
Description   : AT/AT COMPATIBLE
DNShostname   : HP-G1610
Domain        : DOMAIN
Domain Role   : 0
Roles         : {...}
Status        : OK
System Type   : x64-based PC
Thermal State : Safe
```

In general to get a list of an enum :

```
> $Enum ='System.DayOfWeek'
> [Enum]::GetValues($Enum) | ForEach-Object {'{0} {1}' -f [int]$_,$_ }
0 Sunday
1 Monday
2 Tuesday
3 Wednesday
4 Thursday
5 Friday
6 Saturday
```